# I need to render text on a data table

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, datatable

I am working with Data Tables and I have a function that I can't seem to figure out. I am using SSP and I have my columns set up in an array. See below:

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'businessName', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'website',   'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'phone', 'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'streetAddress','dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'city','dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'state','dt' => 5 ),
    array( 'db' => 'zip','dt' => 6 )
);
```

The column website has businesses that don't always have a site. I would like to render a "No site available" for null data and add a "Visit Website" with a link using the pulled data for sites that do have a website.

I can easily do this in php ie:

```
if ($row['website'] == "") {
  $website = "No Website";
}else {
  $website = "<a href='".$row['website']."' rel='_blank'>Visit Website</a>";
}
```

Please point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't shown us your DataTables code. But having said that, take a look at [column rendering](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) and, optionally, also at [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data).

Comment: If you search Stack Overflow for questions using the `datatables` tag and discussing how to add links to cells, you will find [various examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+how+to+add+a+link+site%253Astackoverflow.com).